# Robolectric:: LayoutInflator.inflate() hangs in onCreateOptionsMenu

Tags: java, android, robolectric

I am testing my android app code using robolectric. In one of the activities there is a Layout inflation in `onCreateOptionsMenu` of the activity.

I am trying to test that code using:

```
activityController.create().resume().visible()
```

Here is the contents of onCreateOptionsMenu:

```
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_action_bar, null);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```

But the execution hangs on the `inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_action_bar, null)` line. The strange thing is that this same code, when pasted into the `onCreate` method works flawlessly.

Can anyone help me with what could be the problem here? I am new to Robolectric and android.

Answer (score 0):

`onCreateOptionsMenu()` is meant to create a menu from a `MenuInflater`. Using `LayoutInflater.from(this)` here is a code smell.

See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus#options-menu